# Dont creep backwards on vim escape, without using <esc> mapping

Tags: vim

I have previously used the following vim mapping so that when I press `esc`, vim does not 'creep backwards':

```
:inoremap <silent> <Esc> <Esc>`^
```

However, this has quite unexpected side-effects (to me, at least), for example, now that I have an `<Esc>` on the lhs, the arrow keys won't work anymore in insert mode (and a few other items that send escape sequences to vim.

Is there a better way to do this, or perhaps a settings within vim that alters this behavior? Ultimately, I want the behavior or `` <Esc>`^ ``, I just don't want to have an `<esc>` that is mapped on the lhs for other reasons. What would be the best approach here?

Comment: `What would be the best approach here?` Get used to normal practice. Insert cursor stands "between chars", and normal cursor stands "on char". And so it must move a bit. Learn to use both `i` and `a`, `p` and `P` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

No need to remap `<ESC>`. You could try using this `autocmd` in your `.vimrc`:

```
au InsertLeave * call cursor(getcurpos()[1], getcurpos()[2]+1)
```

This code is a reimplementation of the approach described in the Vim [wiki](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Prevent_escape_from_moving_the_cursor_one_character_to_the_left), which is more verbose (and possibly outdated). The command has a small latency though.

Comment: works well, thank you. Do I need to put this in a `autogroup` or something?

Comment: after testing this out a bit more it seems to allow the cursor to creep forward, so not too useful after adding this to my settings, I wonder what other options there may be...

Comment: @David542 IMHO this is the best one can do without messing too much the configuration of the editor. Remaps of `<ESC>` are not really an option as you can see in the wiki, and this command allows the cursor to "creep backwards" when entering normal mode, just to put it back to its initial position after a second or two. The command cannot send the cursor further than its initial position.